# Mapping one-to-many with several foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_WEIGHTS", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class ItemWeight {

private ItemWeightId id;

@Column(name = "PERCENTAGE", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
private float percentage;

public ItemWeight() {
}

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "itemId", column = @Column(name = "ITEM_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)) })
public ItemWeightId getId() {
    return id;
}

// Setter and Getters
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STORE")
public class Item extends Store {

private List<ItemWeight> weights = new LinkedList<ItemWeight>();    

public Item() {

}

@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "id.itemId")  
public List<ItemWeight> getItemWeights() {
    return weights;
}

public void setItemWeights(List<ItemWeight> weights) {
    this.weights = weights;
}
```

}

My "ITEM_WEIGHTS" table consists 3 primary keys: which SKIN_ID is one of them.

I would like to make the mapping so eventually every "Item" entity will consists a list of all "ItemWeights" that are associated between STORE.ITEM_ID = ITEM_WEIGHTS.ITEM_ID

How can I do that??

Comment: There shouldn't be a basic `itemId` field in `ItemWeightId`. There should be a ManyToOne Item association instead. My advice: stop using composite primary keys, and use single-column, auto-generated PKs instead. Everything will be much easier, cleaner and efficient.

Comment: Thank but my joined table must have 3 primary keys. that is my EmbeddedId.

Comment: If you want to keep this design, make sure to have a ManyToOne Item fields instead of a basic ItemId in your ItemWeightId class. My point is that this design is ugly, and that you should instead use single-column auto-generated PKs. It would be cleaner, easier, and more efficient.